# AngularJS 1.5 call function form JQ, and pass data to component controller function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Guys I also need Your help.How could I call function of my component controller's from JQ function ? And pass data to function controller.I'm really stack on this.

```
function CalendarDashboardController($scope){


var  week = this;


 week.list = [
    {
    name: 'Sun',
    date: Date.now()

},       {
    name: 'Mon',
    date: Date.now()

},       {
    name: 'Tue',
    date: Date.now()

},       {
    name: 'Wed',
    date: Date.now()

},       {
    name: 'Thu',
    date: Date.now()

},       {
    name: 'Fri',
    date: Date.now()

},       {
    name: 'Sat',
    date: Date.now()

}
]



}


mod.component('calendarDashboard', {
templateUrl:"/src/angular-js/partial/calendarDashboard.html",
bindings: {
startdate: '<',
enddate: '<'
},
  controller: CalendarDashboardController

});
```

And I have some function in JS it could be various - But this function should call function from my controller (I didn't create it) because, I don't know how to bind event in my JS cod and controller,and how to pass data to this function.

Comment: Post some code that shows what you are trying to achieve. As currently written the question is unclear.

Comment: I don't know what to do - in JQ I have two variables - "startdate" and "enddate", this variables should be update dynamically, and my component should react on it and rebuild data in template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside some function outside of angular's scope.

Event happen and call some function:

```
function(){

//Here we take $rootScope of our AngularJS module
var fj = angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$rootScope')

        //And apply broadcast event, in further we will catch it
            fj.$apply(function(){
                fj.$broadcast("changeDate",startDate)
                    }               );

}
```

Inside our AngularJS Component Controller:

```
var  ownScope = this;

$scope.$on('changeDate', function(events, args){

    ownScope.startdate = args; //now we've registered!


})
```

To sum up - It will dynamically change data inside our scope and change it in template in our component.